# First order moment of multivariate Gaussian random vector

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expectation

Let $X = (X_1,\dotsc, X_n)$ be a random vector distributed as a multivariate Gaussian with mean $0$ and covariance $\Sigma$. What is $\mathbb{E}[X_1\dots X_n]$?

Comment: Why is it downvoted :(?

Comment: Probably because the question shows little effort on your part. For example; what do you think, what was your attempt, what do you not understand etc...?

Comment: I don't know how to start. For one dimensional, a simple change of variables does the trick.